# How declare a new boolean variable with a number in its name?

Tags: expl3

I want to generate boolean variables (for example `\a1_bool`, `\a2_bool` etc., which depends of value of a variable). But when I generate it, I get an error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   }
l.7 ...xist:NTF{\l__b_\int_eval:N{\g__a_int}_bool}

?
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_gzero_new:N{\g__a_int}
\bool_if_exist:NTF{\l__b_\int_eval:N{\g__a_int}_bool}{\message{variable exists}}{\bool_new:N{\l__b_\int_eval:N{\g__a_int}_bool}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong variant. An `N` argument expects only a single (usually unbraced) argument, so this is correct:

```latex
\bool_if_exist:NTF \l_tmpa_bool { true } { false }
```

while this is wrong:

```latex
\bool_if_exist:NTF { l_tmpa_bool } { true } { false } % WRONG!
```

because the first (`N`) argument you passed to `\bool_if_exist:NTF` is a list of 11 character tokens (`l` `_` `t` `m` `p` `a` `_` `b` `o` `o` `l`).

You want the `c` variant here, to generate a "`c`ontrol sequence name" out of the argument tokens:

```latex
%              ↓
\bool_if_exist:cTF { l_tmpa_bool } { true } { false }
```

The same goes for `\bool_new:c`, instead of `\bool_new:N`. Also, `\int_eval:N` does not exist. The function you want here is `\int_use:N`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_gzero_new:N \g__kozlovskiy_a_int
\bool_if_exist:cTF { l__kozlovskiy_b_ \int_use:N \g__kozlovskiy_a_int _bool }
  { \iow_term:n { variable~exists } }
  { \bool_new:c { l__kozlovskiy_b_ \int_use:N \g__kozlovskiy_a_int _bool } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now,i hope,it's ok,but i want to understood differents betwen N and n. Why the N argument i can't surround by {},because as i here,according the latex rules it better after command use {} for each argument of this command.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy The `N` means a single token as argument, so things like `\l_tmpa_bool`, `a`, `1`, `$`, which are all single tokens can be used in an `N` argument. [The `expl3` package and LaTeX3 programming](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf#subsubsection.0.3.2.6) guide says about `N`: "Single token (unlike `n`, the argument must _not_ be surrounded by braces)". Yes, as you said it will work with braces because that's how TeX will grab an argument, but the guideline is to _not_ use braces for `N` (and `V`)-type arguments.